# labelme json file, extracting cordinates of a rectangle

Tags: python, annotations, conv-neural-network

I am doing an object detection task and annotated my image using labelme. The images were annotated with rectangle bounding boxes in the labelme too. The JSON file of the annotation just shows two-point coordinates instead of four (required to define a rectangle). I need all the four coordinates or two coordinates with the width and height of the rectangle latest so I can prepare the mask. Can someone help me with that

Answer (score 0):

You only need two points to define a bounding box.

Let's say that the 4 point coordinates that form the bounding box are the following:

- (x, y)
- (x + w, y)
- (x, y + h)
- (x + w, y + h)

What LabelMe is showing you the xmin, ymin, xmax and ymax. So, using the example, LabelMe would show you:

```
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>x</xmin>
        <ymin>y</ymin>
        <xmax>x+w</xmax>
        <ymax>y+h</ymax>
    </bndbox>
```

Which is enough to get the other 2 point coordinates.

Comment: Thank you so much! I should have figured that out myself. Appreciate your help!